# How can I get the ID as value and Name to display in dropdownlist php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

i have a problem with that i need to get the value from the dropdown list to be a number and the name for a kategory to be the name that the user picks.

```
<select name="kategori">
<?php
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT KategoriID from Kategori");
    $second=mysql_query("SELECT KategoriNavn from Kategori");
    while($r=mysql_fetch_row($query) && $v=mysql_fetch_row($second)){
        echo "<option value='$r[0]>$v[0]</option>";
    }
?>
```

This is the code i have, but i cant make it to work. 
Im kinda new to PHP. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `echo "<option value='".$r[0].$v[0]."'>".$r[0].$v[0]."</option>";` ? are you wanting `$r` and `$v` next to each other? I'm not sure what you expect the output to be as you haven't stated the problem with what you have. I would also like to recommend you to change to mysqli

Comment: @NewToJS , I want the value to be r, and the name to be v

Comment: Then use this... `echo "<option value='".$r[0]."'>".$v[0]."</option>";` if you have any more problems then please post and error reports any make sure the php is outputting the data. Example `die($r[0].$v[0]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to write two different queries. You could have written just a single one. I think mysql fetch_assoc is a tad easier to understand.

You can try something like this:

```
  <?php

     $query = mysql_query("SELECT KategoriID, KategoriNavn  from Kategori") or die(mysql_error()); // Debugging displays SQL syntax errors, if any.

     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($query);
     exit;              // Let me know what the array looks like.

     while ($r= mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>

   <option value=<?php echo $r['KategoriID']; ?> > 
      <?php echo $r['KategoriNavn']; ?>
   </option>

   <?php } ?>

   <?php 

         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($_POST); // Do this where you're checking your POST data
         exit;
     ?>
```

Assuming you want option value to be KategoriNavn and the option to display to be KategoriID.

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: I get this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\...mypage.php on line 168"
Line 168 is the "echo" line

Comment: On my upload.php i have $kategori = $_POST['kategori']; and I need an int value into the table. When i run the code it does not insert it into the database table because the value from kategori isnt a number

Comment: Okay, please refer to y edited post and print_r your $_POST and let me know the array you get.

Comment: Nothing happens, i now cant choose a kategory and it does not print anything